# About cv2. How can I make the VideoWriter save as bytes instead of outputfile?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to upload the video data to the Operations support system right after finished writing. Saving as outputfile is not necessary in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello gcz and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly. A full working peace of code would be helpful to understand what you actually ask.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV doesn't support this unfortunately. But you could use a RAMDisk to do what you want.

For Linux

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

Then save your video stream to /mnt/ramdisk/ with OpenCV and read from there. It shouldn't save to disk this way.

```
video_file = '/mnt/ramdisk/video.mp4'
out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_file,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame_width,frame_height))
with open(video_file,'r') as f:
    #do stuff here
```

When you're done:

```
umount /tmp/ramdisk/
```

There is a pip module memory-tempfile if you want to manage the ramdisk with python